# How do I run some code after every single controller hit to a server in grails

Tags: grails

I've got my own equivalent to transactions that I need to do commits or rollbacks at the very end of a request.  I'm using afterInterceptor, but I believe that runs before the view is rendered.  The view rendering may do stuff that I need to have encapsulated in this transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be exactly sure this is what you are after but [Grails filters](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) will give you a post render hook: [see this also](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html)

There are 3 inteceptors on a filter:

- before
- after - run after an action
- afterView - run after the view is rendered, might be the one for you

There should be an implicit variable 'request' that you could potentially get any params from